# How to perform long event processing in Node JS with a message queue?

Tags: node.js, message-queue, publish-subscribe

I am building an email processing pipeline in Node JS with Google Pub/Sub as a message queue. The message queue has a limitation where it needs an acknowledgment for a sent message within 10 minutes. However, the jobs it's sending to the Node JS server might take an hour to complete. So the same job might run multiple times till one of them finishes. I'm worried that this will block the Node JS event loop and slow down the server too.

Find an architecture diagram attached. My questions are:

1. Should I be using a message queue to start this long-running job given that the message queue expects a response in 10 mins or is there some other architecture I should consider?
2. If multiple such jobs start, should I be worried about the Node JS event loop being blocked. Each job is basically iterating through a MongoDB cursor creating hundreds of thousands of emails.

[image: architecture diagram]

Comment: Well, it sounds like you either should not be using that queue (with the timeout you can't change) or you should break up your jobs into something that easily finishes long before the timeouts.

Comment: I rather doubt you have nodejs event loop blockage issues as long as all your I/O is using asynchronous methods.  Nothing you're doing sounds CPU-heavy and that's what blocks the event loop.  Your whole project is probably limited by both MongoDB and whatever you're using to send the emails so you should probably make sure you're not overwhelming either one of those to the point where they become sluggish and lose throughput.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that I likely don't have to be worried about event loop blocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the original question:

> 1. Should I be using a message queue to start this long-running job given that the message queue expects a response in 10 mins or is there
>    some other architecture I should consider?

Yes, a message queue works well for dealing with these kinds of events. The important thing is to make sure the final action is idempotent, so that even if you process duplicate events by accident, the final result is applied once. This [guide](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-pro-tips-building-idempotent-functions) from Google Cloud is a helpful resource on making your subscriber idempotent.

To get around the 10 min limit of Pub/Sub, I ended up creating an in-memory table that tracked active jobs. If a job was actively being processed and Pub/Sub sent the message again, it would do nothing. If the server restarts and loses the job, the in-memory table also disappears, so the job can be processed once again if it was incomplete.

> 2. If multiple such jobs start, should I be worried about the Node JS event loop being blocked. Each job is basically iterating through a
>    MongoDB cursor creating hundreds of thousands of emails.
>    I have ignored this for now as per the comment left by jfriend00. You can also rate-limit the number of jobs being processed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it sounds like you either should not be using that queue (with the timeout you can't change) or you should break up your jobs into something that easily finishes long before the timeouts.  It sounds like a case of you just need to match the tool with the requirements of the job.  If that queue doesn't match your requirements, you probably need a different mechanism.  I don't fully understand what you need from Google's pub/sub, but creating a queue of your own or finding a generic queue on NPM is generally fairly easy if you just want to serialize access to a bunch of jobs.

I rather doubt you have nodejs event loop blockage issues as long as all your I/O is using asynchronous methods. Nothing you're doing sounds CPU-heavy and that's what blocks the event loop (long running CPU-heavy operations). Your whole project is probably limited by both MongoDB and whatever you're using to send the emails so you should probably make sure you're not overwhelming either one of those to the point where they become sluggish and lose throughput.